# Python: read the content of a text file and look for a match/condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I m trying to open up a text file and look for string `Num_row_lables`. If the value for `Num_row_labels` is greater than or equal to 10, then print the name of the file.

In the example below, my text file `test.mrk` has some text in the format below: P.s., my text file doesn't have `Num_row_labels >= 10`. It always has "`equal to`".

```
Format= { Window_Type="Tabular", Tabular= { Num_row_labels=10 } }
```

so I created a variable `teststring` to hold the pattern I will be looking at.
Then I opened the file.

Then using `re`, I got `Num_row_labels=10` in my variable called match.
Using `group()` on match, I extracted the threshold number I wanted and using `int()` converted the `string to int`.

My purpose is to read the text file to `find/print` the value for Num_row_labels along with the name of file if the text file has Num_row_labels = 10 or any # greater than 10.

Here's my test code:

```
import os
import os.path
import re

teststring = """Format= { Window_Type="Tabular", Tabular= { Num_row_labels=10 } }"""
fname = "E:\MyUsers\ssbc\test.mrk"
fo = open(fname, "r")
match = re.search('Num_row_labels=(\d+)', teststring)
tnum = int(match.group(1))


if(tnum>=10):
        print(fname)
```

How do I make sure that I m searching the match in the content of opened file and checking the condition for tnum>=10? My test code would simply print the file name only on the basis of last 4 lines. I want to be sure that the search is all over the content of my text file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

so what you want to do is to read out the whole file as a string, and search for your pattern on that string

```
with open(fname, "r") as fo:
    content_as_string = fo.read()
    match = re.search('Num_row_labels=(\d+)', content_as_string)
    # do want you want to the matchings
```

Answer (score 3):

***Python code to read file content based on condition***

```
    file = '../input/testtxt/kaggle.txt'
    output = []
    with open(file, 'r') as fp:
        lines = fp.readlines()
        for i in lines:
            if('Image for' in i):
                output.append(i)
            
    print(output)
```